# find the first occurrence of a value (from a list of values)in a pandas dataframe and return the index of the row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame (the actual data set is far larger and contains numbers from 1-50):

```
          date           main   N1  N2  N3  N4  N5
0   2020-09-18  7-12-14-40-42   7   12  14  40  42
1   2020-09-11  2-5-24-43-45    2   5   24  43  45
2   2020-09-04  5-23-28-38-49   5   23  28  38  49
3   2020-08-28  8-11-22-38-41   8   11  22  38  41
4   2020-08-21  26-27-30-46-49  26  27  30  46  49
```

I want to return the row index for the first occurrence of each number. So far the only way that I have been able to achieve this is by "manually" using

```
lotteryData.loc[(lotteryData.N5==1)].head(49)
```

which in this example gives row index number 2. This is obviously very clumsy and does not take advantage of the Pandas DataFrame capability at all. Is there a way of iterating through the list in the format 5-23-28-38-49 directly to capture this information or a way to iterate through the columns to find the first occurrence of all numbers between 1 and 50

Comment: Can you show your expected output ?

Comment: Ideally I want a new dataframe with the number and the row index as a value e.g 49 and 2 in the above example ( the index on this data set actually reflects weeks).the example above using loc outputs the row with the index

Comment: For each column; group by `Series(np.arrange(1,51))`, get the index of the first item in each group. You want the first occurrence of a number in **any** of the columns or the first occurrence in **each** column?

Comment: the index of the first occurrence of a number in any of the columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do `stack` the `drop_duplicates`

```
out = df.loc[:,'N2':].stack().drop_duplicates()
0  N2    12
   N3    14
   N4    40
   N5    42
1  N2     5
   N3    24
   N4    43
   N5    45
2  N2    23
   N3    28
   N4    38
   N5    49
3  N2    11
   N3    22
   N5    41
4  N2    27
   N3    30
   N4    46
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you. That has worked perfectly Now to get it into the format that I would like.I will need to read the functionality of stack() and drop_duplicates() to understand it properly. May I ask how to get the number and the index into a new dataframe? While the output is clear, I am not sure how to use it in a dataframe